# Validating GitHub Webhook HMAC signature in Go

Tags: go, webhooks, github-api, hmacsha1

I've written the following function for validating the `X-Hub-Signature` request header returned by the GitHub API as part of the webhook's payload.

```
func isValidSignature(r *http.Request, key string) bool {
    // Assuming a non-empty header
    gotHash := strings.SplitN(r.Header.Get("X-Hub-Signature"), "=", 2)
    if gotHash[0] != "sha1" {
        return false
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cannot read the request body: %s\n", err)
        return false
    }

    hash := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(key))
    if _, err := hash.Write(b); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cannot compute the HMAC for request: %s\n", err)
        return false
    }

    expectedHash := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
    log.Println("EXPECTED HASH:", expectedHash)
    return gotHash[1] == expectedHash
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as I'm not able to validate with the correct `secret`. Here is an example output, if that helps:

```
HUB SIGNATURE: sha1=026b77d2284bb95aa647736c42f32ea821d6894d
EXPECTED HASH: 86b6fa48bf7643494dc3a8459a8af70008f6881a
```

I've used the logic from [hmac-examples](https://github.com/danharper/hmac-examples#go) repo as a guideline and implemented the code. However, I am unable to understand the reason behind this discrepancy.

I would be grateful if someone can point out the trivial mistake I'm making here.

Refer: [Delivery Headers](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#delivery-headers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really embarrasing but still I would like to share how I was able to fix it.

*I sent in the wrong `key` as the input which was causing all the confusion.*

Lessons learnt:

1. The above code snippet is absolutely **correct** and can be used as a validator.
2. Every one makes stupid mistakes but only the wise own up to them and rectify.